# Is the minimal conjunctive normal form for positive formula unique? If so, how do you calculate it?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

I am considering positive Boolean formulas (no negations). Take for example $A$. Here are two of its positive [conjunctive normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).

$$A$$
$$A \land (A \lor B)$$

The minimal example is $A$.

Does every positive boolean formula have a unique minimal conjunctive normal form? If so, how does one calculate it?

(I conjecture that you can do so by finding a positive conjuctive normal form, and then pruning any terms that are implied by other terms (for example, $A \lor B$ is implied by the previous term $A$, so it gives no additional information in a conjuction). I don't know how to prove that this is correct, if it is so. (It is also not very efficient.))

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

This showed up on the Wikipedia Math Help Desk, see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2018_December_6#Minimal_CNF_form). It looks like the minimal expression is unique for positive expressions.

**Proof:** Let *S* and *T* be two equivalent positive expressions in CNF which are both minimal. Let {S<sub>i</sub>} be the set of clauses in *S* and {T<sub>j</sub>} be the set of clauses in *T*. Each S<sub>i</sub> and T<sub>j</sub>, in turn, corresponds to a subset of a set of Boolean variables {x<sub>k</sub>}. Since *S* is minimal, no S<sub>i</sub> is contained in S<sub>j</sub> for j≠i, and similarly for *T*. For each assignment a:x<sub>k</sub> → {*T*, *F*}, define Z(a) to be the set of variables for which a is *F*, i.e. Z(a) is the compliment of the support of a. A clause S<sub>i</sub> evaluates to *F* iff S<sub>i</sub>⊆Z(a) and the expression *S* evaluates to *F* iff S<sub>i</sub>⊆Z(a) for some i. A similar statements holds for T. Fix i and define the truth assignment a<sub>i</sub>(x<sub>k</sub>) to be *T* when x<sub>k</sub> is *not* in S<sub>i</sub>, in other words a<sub>i</sub> is the truth assignment so that Z(a<sub>i</sub>) = S<sub>i</sub>. The clause S<sub>i</sub> evaluates to *F* under this assignment, so *S* evaluates to *F*. But *S* and *T* are equivalent so *T* evaluates to *F*. Therefore T<sub>j</sub>⊆Z(a<sub>i</sub>)= S<sub>i</sub> for some j. Similarly, for each j there is k so that S<sub>k</sub> ⊆ T<sub>j</sub>. (I think another way of saying this is that *S* and *T* are refinements of each other.) If S<sub>i</sub> is an element of *S*, then there is T<sub>j</sub> in *T* so that T<sub>j</sub> ⊆ S<sub>i</sub>, and there is an S<sub>k</sub> so that S<sub>k</sub> ⊆ T<sub>j</sub>. Then S<sub>k</sub> ⊆ S<sub>i</sub> and so, since ''S'' is minimal, i=k. We then have S<sub>i</sub> ⊆ T<sub>j</sub> ⊆ S<sub>i</sub>, S<sub>i</sub> = T<sub>j</sub> ∈ *T*. So *S* ⊆ *T* and similarly *T* ⊆ *S*, therefore *S* = *T*.

Another (probably better) approach is to characterize the clauses that appear.

Comment: This seems to be folklore in logics, yet I don't find anything to cite for this. Surely this must appear in some old book or something...

Comment: @M.Monet. Isn't this simply a proof by duality? If I have two equivalent minimal positive CNF expressions, then applying de Morgan's law I can replace ANDs by ORs and ORs by ANDs, replace each variable by the negated variable, and obtain two positive DNF expressions for the negated function, hence they are still equivalent. Further, these DNFs are also minimal (minimality says that the sets of variables of the clauses are pairwise incomparable). Hence the DNFs must be the same, and the initial CNFs must also be the same.