# Is it possible for the DNF and CNF to be the same

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

Is it possible for a formula in propositional logic that its disjunctive normal form (DNF) and its conjunctive normal form (CNF) are the same?

For example, can $A \land C$ be both the conjunctive normal form and the disjunctive normal form of the formula below?

> $(A \lor ((A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land  \lnot C))) \land C$

Comment: Can you add your work to show how you simplified the highlighted expression to $A\land C$?

Comment: Yes, the formula $A \land C$ can both be interpreted as CNF and DNF.

Answer (score 2):

A conjunctive normal form is a conjunction of a sequence of disjunctions of a sequence of literals or their negations.   Abreviated as: a conjunction of disjunctions of literals or their negations.

A single literal is a conjunction of a sequence of one literal.   It is also a disjunction of a sequence of one literal.

Thus $A\wedge C$ is a conjunction of two disjunctions of one literal; and also a disjunction of two conjunctions of one literal.   That is it is both a conjunctive normal form and a disjunctive normal form.

---

Now, is it a CNF/DNF for $(A\vee((A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge\neg B\wedge\neg C)))\wedge C$?

Well, $C$ must be true for the statement to hold.   When we substitue $\top$ for $C$, that becomes $(A\vee((A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge\neg B\wedge \bot)))\wedge \top$ which simpliefies to $A$.   So $A$ must be true too.   The value of $B$ is irrelevant.

Therefore $A\wedge C$ is indeed a CNF/DNF equivalent to the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: yes!

Indeed, $A \land C$ is both a [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (because it is a conjunction of two disjunctive clauses, each one made of just one literal) and a [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (with just one conjunctive clause).

To prove that $A \land C$ is a CNF and a DNF *of* $(A \lor ((A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land  \lnot C))) \land C$, it remains to prove that $A \land C$ is logically equivalent to $(A \lor ((A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land  \lnot C))) \land C$. To prove it, I use logical equivalences listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) as rewriting rules (the use of the associativity is left implicit):

\begin{align} 
(A \lor (A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land  \lnot C)) \land C &\equiv (A \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land  \lnot C)) \land C &\text{absortion law} \\
&\equiv (A \lor \lnot A) \land (A \lor \lnot B) \land (A \lor \lnot C) \land C &\text{distributivity law} \\
&\equiv (A \lor \lnot B) \land (A \lor \lnot C) \land C &\text{identity law} \\
&\equiv (A \lor (\lnot B \land \lnot C)) \land C &\text{distributivity law} \\
&\equiv (A\land C) \lor (\lnot B \land \lnot C \land C) &\text{distributivity law} \\
&\equiv A\land C &\text{identity law}
\end{align}
where the first identity law can be applied since $A \lor \lnot A$ is a tautology, and the second identity law can be applied because $\lnot B \land \lnot C \land C$ is a contradiction.

---

*Remark*. Pay attention that a CNF of a given formula is not unique, and similarly for DNF. For instance, also $A \land C \land (B \lor \lnot B)$ is a CNF of $(A \lor ((A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land  \lnot C))) \land C$. So, properly speaking it is not clear what you refer to when you talk of *the* CNF (or *the* DNF) of a given formula.

More interesting remarks about the non-uniqueness of CNF (or DNF) of a given formula are in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1962707/288417).